# jquery script to check if textbox is blank, or checkbox is checked

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I am using client ID's to check if a textbox is blank, which in my script works but when checking if the checkbox is checked it doesnt do anything

here is my script

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>  
    <script type="text/javascript">  
        $(function () {
            $('#<%=lbtnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
                var txt = $('#<%=txtPhotoAndVideoConsentIfNot.TextBoxID %>');

                if ((txt.val() != null && txt.val() != '')) {
                    alert('filled in');
                } else {
                    alert('empty ');
                }

                if $('#<%= cbPhotoAndVideoConsent.ClientID %>').is(':checked') {
                    alert("TEst");
                }

            })
        });
    </script>
```

Using the client id for the button, textbox and the checkbox. The IF for the checkbox works but the other doesnt.

My aim is, i have a form which contains the textbox and checkbox, and the user MUST fill in one or the other

Appreciate the help

Comment: Why are you loading jQuery twice? Remove one, and consider loading a much newer one. Also please click the `<>` snippet editor and provide a [mcve] without any ASP. This is not an ASP question. Also your script only checks the fields when the page loads. Not anytime later

Comment: Chances are loading jquery twice is causing issues.

Comment: @marco - Oh right, any ideas on how i can check box checkbox and textbox?

Answer (score 0):

Multiple issues:

- Remove one line for loading jquery
- There is no TextBoxID property
- You are missing ( ) parenthesis around your if statement

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">  
  $(function () {
      $('#<%=lbtnSave.ClientID %>').click(function () {
          var txt = $('#<%=txtPhotoAndVideoConsentIfNot.ClientID %>'); //fix ClientID

          if ((txt.val() != null && txt.val() != '')) {
              alert('filled in');
          } else {
              alert('empty ');
          }
          if ($('#<%= cbPhotoAndVideoConsent.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) { //add parenthesis here
              alert("TEst");
          }
      })
  }
</script>
```

To catch those errors, just open up your developer tools in your browser by pressing F12 and watch the console window. This will print out javascript errors to you.

//edit:
if you want to combine both conditions, simple do it like this:

```
if ((txt.val() != null && txt.val() != '') && $('#<%= cbPhotoAndVideoConsent.ClientID %>').is(':checked')) {
    alert('filled in');
} else {
    alert('empty ');
}
```

Comment: Brilliant that works a lot better! I am now trying to join the 2 if statements to check both - along the lines of  -- if ((txt.val() != null && txt.val() != '') && $('#<%= cbPhotoAndVideoConsent.ClientID %>').is(':checked') == true) {..}

Comment: Brilliant Marco works like a charm! 1 last question sorry, on the else where it alerts "empty" i dont want it to reload the page .. is this a return false? or is there another way to do it

Comment: If this is an asp:button then `return false` should prevent it, or setting `AutoPostBack=false` in your markup.